# Trying to print $_POST doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to print the values of any textfields. I'm using AJAX, jQuery and PHP, but the code doesn't work. It doesn't show any inside the `div id='pinta'`, it is empty.

JavaScript:

```
$('#Enviar0').click(function() {
            var input1 =$('#primero input').serialize();
            $.ajax({ 
                   type:"POST",
                   url:"pintaParte.php",
                   data:input1,                   
                   success: function(data) {
                            $("#pinta").html(data);
                   }
            });         
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
   foreach ($_POST['input1'] as $key => $value) {
        echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
        echo "<hr />";
   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: The input you're serializing MUST have a field named `input1`, or your php code will not work. Try doing a `var_dump($_POST)` instead.

Comment: probably: `data: {"input1": input1}` instead of `data: input1`

Comment: You have local JS variable named `input1`. But you just pass its value, not a named array to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not explicitly specifying the name of the post variable it will not exist server-side.

Your data element should probably look like:

`data: {"input1": input1}`

Comment: If the input has a name attribute of 'input1' it should work fine.

Comment: @TomHartman - No harm in being explicit however, especially in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using JSON:

```
$('#Enviar0').click(function()
{
    var input1 = $('#primero input').serialize();
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "pintaParte.php",
    data: {"input1": input1}            
    success: function(data)
    {
        var key;
        var value;
        var string = '';
        // You have to parse the json array.
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++)
        {
            key = data[i].key;
            value = data[i].value;
            string += "<p>"+key+"</p>";
            string += "<p>"+value+"</p>";
        }
        $("#pinta").html(string);
    });         
});
```

Where pintaParte.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    $input1 = isset($_POST['input1']) ? $_POST['input1'] : array();

    if(sizeof($input1) == 0)
    {
        $json[] = array();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($input1 as $key => $value)
        {
            $json[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
    flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that to read a named object attribute, you need to set that as a key value in a JavaScript object - at the moment you're just passing a string.

Try this:

```
$('#Enviar0').click(function() {
    var input1 =$('#primero input').serialize();
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST",
        url:"pintaParte.php",
        data: {
            input1: input1
        },                   
        success: function(data) {
            $("#pinta").html(data);
        }
    });         
});
```

You'll find using a browser-based AJAX explorer very helpful for debugging these sorts of issues. Chrome and Safari have one built in, and Firefox has the Firebug plugin. These will let you watch an operation in real-time, including the GET/POST parameters that are actually being sent.

Comment: @jal: Try using the browser-based debugging methods I've suggested. Without access to this information, anyone here would just be guessing what the problem is. Ensure you don't have any JS errors in your browser console, too.

Comment: Consider putting an `alert` in the success handler also, to see if that is actually getting called.

Comment: I tried to use an alert in the success, but it doesnt show any. Im using firebug, and my browser is Firefox

Comment: Right, so carry on debugging then `:-)` - that is useful information. Does the AJAX operation show in Firebug? Is a key called `input1` sent to the server? Is it reaching the correct server-side URI?

Comment: Aha, [the example you cited](http://www.informatica-politecnico.com/webS23/pracREPASO/pA12.php) in your now-deleted comment doesn't use AJAX at all - see the source code for how they did it `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key from your foreach loop:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
        echo "<hr />";
   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: From the JS, it looks like the key `input1` is the serialised contents of the form.