# Passing javascript array to php to print values does not work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass a javascript array to php to print the values, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

javascript

```
   $('#Enviar0').click(function() {
        var buttons0 = [];
        for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
            buttons0[i]+= $('butEnv'+i).val();
            alert($('butEnv'+i).val());
        }
        var array=buttons0.toJSONString();
        $.ajax({ 
               type:"POST",
               url:"pintaParte.php",
               data: {encapsulado:array},
               success: function(data) {
                        $("#pinta").html(data);
               }
        });         
    });
```

php

```
$buttons0=parseJSON($_POST['encapsulado']);
foreach ($buttons0 as $value) {
    echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: What "is not working"? We are not mindreaders.

Comment: What's the content of your `parseJSON()` function? Why don't you just use `json_decode()`?

Comment: firebug says the error is here:
var array=buttons0.toJSONString();

Comment: json contents 4 strings.

Comment: what am I doing wrong in the array? Array contents: txt0, txt1, txt2, txt3.

Comment: Since a number of us [solved the first part of your problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133567/trying-to-print-post-doesnt-work), it is customary to acknowledge that help before moving on.

Comment: @halfer: I solved the problem. Sorry sometimes is difficult to me explain the problems. I will try to be more explicit and clear writing questions. regards

Answer (score 4):

use `JSON.stringify()` on the client side:

```
$.ajax({ 
               type:"POST",
               url:"pintaParte.php",
               data: JSON.stringify({encapsulado:array}),
               success: function(data) {
                        $("#pinta").html(data);
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if your array is ok in the php side (after the ajax call) ?

If you can't get your array in the php side, maybe in your javascript try to simply use...

```
data : "encapsulado=" + array
```

And in your php code, try to put all values of the array in one string and just make only one echo and then a return.

```
$str = "";
foreach ($buttons0 as $value) {
    $str = $str.$value.'<br>';
}
echo $str;
return;
```

Try to use a tool like firebug or the Chrome dev tool to see parameters and responses in your http requests and be abble to localize the error (in the client side or in the server side).

Hope this helps !